# How to sticky a button at bottom of page while page scroll down with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a long list of update-able inputs. User can update the values as he/she scrolls through this list and when they are done inputting the values, they should scroll down to the end of the list to find the "update" button.

I want this button to be visible hovering at the bottom of the screen (as long as the user is scrolling within the div) so the user doesn't have to scroll down all the way to the end to find the button.

Please let me know if I can further explain the problem if I'm not clear.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried adding a fixed position button to the bottom of the screen, but it shows even after the `<div>` which looks unprofessional. Here is the code I want hovering at the bottom of the screen until I reach its original place.

```
<div><input class="button" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Update Referral Ids"></div>
```

Comment: Can you include your code and explain exactly what is not working?

Comment: Try looking into `position: sticky;`

Comment: I have included the code which generates the inputs (and I have 90+ inputs)

Comment: Why has my question gotten a negative point? I used the wizard to create a good question :(

Comment: @ninadepina I think this is the simplest way to go and thanks for the insightful answer. Now, my problem is I want the button appear when I am much closer to the header than it is positioned.

Comment: @SiamakEnsafi Your question has surely received negative votes because you provide us a PHP code but your question is for CSS / HTML (We can't basically do anything with your PHP code).
You should provide just enough code to allow us to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SiamakEnsafi Your html uses `<center>` tags which are deprecated in HTML5. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center
Also, your html is not complete, I just have a button on my page. And a `<form>` and `<div>` tag are closed without being opened.
Your CSS code is also missing.

Comment: Also for html and css snippet, you can use Stack Snippet. See how to use it : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/9947331

Comment: @SioGabx It's done. Thank you so much for the information. I have bookmarked this question so that in the future, I would be able to go back to your comments and post properly (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the button inside a div with an ID like "sticky", then add the following CSS (Thank you @ninadepina for the original idea):

```
#sticky {padding: 2rem; background: gray; position: sticky; bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: It's not working for elements that are created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property of position :fixed; for the element to stuck at specific position even after the page is scrolled